# How to hide/disable the legend box in Highcharts.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I would like to ask if it is possible to just hide all the legend box in a chart using HighCharts.js library?

```
var chart_object = {
chart: {
    renderTo: render_to,
    type: graph_type
},
colors:graph_colors,
title: {
    text: ''
},
xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: x_axis.title,
        margin: 15
    },
    categories: categories,

},
(...)           
};

 // Create the chart
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_object);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, the easiest way I've found to do that is just adding the **legend attribute** to chart_object  and set *enabled* to false:
Sample:

```
var chart_object = {
 chart: {
 renderTo: render_to,
 type: graph_type
},
legend:{ enabled:false },
colors:graph_colors,
(...)
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. API docs:https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.enabled

Comment: this worked.. but is there any way we can still show the legend, but disable it?

Answer (score 5):

In case when you need do it dynamically, you can use this solution

```
 $('#updateLegend').click(function (e) {
        var legend = chart.legend; 

        if(legend.display) {
            legend.group.hide();
            legend.box.hide();
            legend.display = false;
        } else {

            legend.group.show();
            legend.box.show();
            legend.display = true;
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/3Bh7b/1/

Comment: var legend = SebastianBochan;