# How to re-create the same chart in Highcharts as seen on the mock?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, linechart

I am trying to re-create the following line chart using the Highcharts library. Can somebody tell me how can I make sure that the year on the x-axis at the bottom start from 2010 and go up to 2020. The year only has to repeat once. I would also like to know how can I set the same y-axis label as shown on the image below as well:

[image: chart]

This is what my code looks like:
https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/w4rtk15g/3/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'line',
    zoomType: 'x'
},
title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Inflation'
    }
},

xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
},

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest result I could get so far - I couldn't hide the tooltip, but, I think it's pretty close to your desired result.

> **NOTE**: The results of the chart depends of the data, so, the exact graphic lines aren't the same as in your image; this jsfiddle is an
> example you can use for customize it.

See here the [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/mwstz8qu/).

Code:

```js
/*
    Sources:
  
  * https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes
  
  * https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes
  
  * https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines
  
  * https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-dashstyle-all/
  
  * https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.DashStyleValue
  
  * https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-step/
  
  * https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highcharts
  
  * https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes?_ga=2.227511582.220005933.1619809828-761661522.1619809828
  
  * https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.lineColor
  
  * https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/linecolor/
  
  * https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickcolor/
  
  * https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickColor
  
  * https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530159/12511801
  
  * https://stackoverflow.com/a/20983707/12511801
  
  * 
  
*/

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value:.1f}%',
      valueDecimals: 1,
      step: 2, // i.e: 0.1, 0.2, etc. It depends of the data, though.
      // Style: not sure if there is a better way:
      // Source: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.labels.style
      style: {
        color: '#000000'
      }
    },
    custom: {
      allowNegativeLog: false
    },
    plotLines: [{
      color: 'black', // Color value
      dashStyle: 'LongDash', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
      value: 0.1, // Value of where the line will appear
      width: 4 // Width of the line    
    }],
    // Color of the y-axis line:
    lineColor: '#000000',
    lineWidth: 3,

    // Color of the y-axis tick lines: 
    tickColor: '#000000',
    tickWidth: 3,

    // Hide grid-lines on the y-axis:
    gridLineWidth: 0
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      step: 4, // i.e: 1950, 1990, etc. It depends of the data, though.
      // Style: not sure if there is a better way:
      // Source: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.labels.style
      style: {
        color: '#000000'
      }
    },
    plotBands: [
      // set the gray plotBand.
      {
        color: '#D2DAE6',
        from: Date.UTC(1952, 0, 2), // Start of the plot band
        to: Date.UTC(1957, 0, 4) // End of the plot band
      },
      // set the yellow plotBand.
      {
        color: '#FDED96',
        from: Date.UTC(1968, 0, 2), // Start of the plot band
        to: Date.UTC(1970, 0, 4) // End of the plot band
      }
    ],
    // Color of the x-axis line:
    lineColor: '#000000',
    lineWidth: 3,

    // Color of the x-axis tick lines: 
    tickColor: '#000000',
    tickWidth: 3
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },

  legend: {
    /*layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'*/
    enabled: false
  },

  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    valueDecimals: 2
  },

  colors: [
    "#000000"
  ],

  series: [{
    name: 'Inflation',
    data: [{
      "x": -694310400000.0,
      "y": 0.10242085661080069
    }, {
      "x": -691632000000.0,
      "y": 0.09481961147086038
    }, {
      "x": -689126400000.0,
      "y": 0.06818181818181812
    }, {
      "x": -686448000000.0,
      "y": 0.08272727272727276
    }, {
      "x": -683856000000.0,
      "y": 0.09384965831435088
    }, {
      "x": -681177600000.0,
      "y": 0.09375
    }, {
      "x": -678585600000.0,
      "y": 0.09761583445793964
    }, {
      "x": -675907200000.0,
      "y": 0.09062499999999996
    }, {
      "x": -673228800000.0,
      "y": 0.06654991243432562
    }, {
      "x": -670636800000.0,
      "y": 0.061108686163247494
    }, {
      "x": -667958400000.0,
      "y": 0.047701647875108444
    }, {
      "x": -665366400000.0,
      "y": 0.02733874412644166
    }, {
      "x": -662688000000.0,
      "y": 0.013935810810810967
    }, {
      "x": -660009600000.0,
      "y": 0.010139416983523386
    }, {
      "x": -657590400000.0,
      "y": 0.01744680851063829
    }, {
      "x": -654912000000.0,
      "y": 0.004198152812762368
    }, {
      "x": -652320000000.0,
      "y": -0.004164931278633932
    }, {
      "x": -649641600000.0,
      "y": -0.009523809523809379
    }, {
      "x": -647049600000.0,
      "y": -0.02868852459016391
    }, {
      "x": -644371200000.0,
      "y": -0.02988129349160873
    }, {
      "x": -641692800000.0,
      "y": -0.02504105090311981
    }, {
      "x": -639100800000.0,
      "y": -0.026326614561908546
    }, {
      "x": -636422400000.0,
      "y": -0.019039735099337762
    }, {
      "x": -633830400000.0,
      "y": -0.018295218295218296
    }, {
      "x": -631152000000.0,
      "y": -0.02082465639316955
    }, {
      "x": -628473600000.0,
      "y": -0.012547051442910906
    }, {
      "x": -626054400000.0,
      "y": -0.01129234629861986
    }, {
      "x": -623376000000.0,
      "y": -0.011287625418060276
    }, {
      "x": -620784000000.0,
      "y": -0.0058552906733584376
    }, {
      "x": -618105600000.0,
      "y": -0.0016722408026756952
    }, {
      "x": -615513600000.0,
      "y": 0.01561181434599157
    }, {
      "x": -612835200000.0,
      "y": 0.021097046413502074
    }, {
      "x": -610156800000.0,
      "y": 0.024842105263158
    }, {
      "x": -607564800000.0,
      "y": 0.0350654837346851
    }, {
      "x": -604886400000.0,
      "y": 0.03797468354430378
    }, {
      "x": -602294400000.0,
      "y": 0.0580262600592969
    }, {
      "x": -599616000000.0,
      "y": 0.07954062101233506
    }, {
      "x": -596937600000.0,
      "y": 0.09402795425667088
    }, {
      "x": -594518400000.0,
      "y": 0.09475465313028764
    }, {
      "x": -591840000000.0,
      "y": 0.09598308668076116
    }, {
      "x": -589248000000.0,
      "y": 0.09339503575936048
    }, {
      "x": -586569600000.0,
      "y": 0.08584589614740379
    }, {
      "x": -583977600000.0,
      "y": 0.07644370585791438
    }, {
      "x": -581299200000.0,
      "y": 0.06859504132231398
    }, {
      "x": -578620800000.0,
      "y": 0.06943303204601481
    }, {
      "x": -576028800000.0,
      "y": 0.06775510204081625
    }, {
      "x": -573350400000.0,
      "y": 0.06991869918699178
    }, {
      "x": -570758400000.0,
      "y": 0.05964771817453962
    }, {
      "x": -568080000000.0,
      "y": 0.042159180457052914
    }, {
      "x": -565401600000.0,
      "y": 0.02245451025938827
    }, {
      "x": -562896000000.0,
      "y": 0.019706336939721902
    }, {
      "x": -560217600000.0,
      "y": 0.02083333333333326
    }, {
      "x": -557625600000.0,
      "y": 0.018468641785302164
    }, {
      "x": -554947200000.0,
      "y": 0.02313922097956045
    }, {
      "x": -552355200000.0,
      "y": 0.029718255499807
    }, {
      "x": -549676800000.0,
      "y": 0.03209590100541382
    }, {
      "x": -546998400000.0,
      "y": 0.023050326546292688
    }, {
      "x": -544406400000.0,
      "y": 0.020259938837920544
    }, {
      "x": -541728000000.0,
      "y": 0.014057750759878473
    }, {
      "x": -539136000000.0,
      "y": 0.009066868152625585
    }, {
      "x": -536457600000.0,
      "y": 0.007183364839319584
    }, {
      "x": -533779200000.0,
      "y": 0.006815600151457879
    }, {
      "x": -531360000000.0,
      "y": 0.009094353921940135
    }, {
      "x": -528681600000.0,
      "y": 0.008692365835222926
    }, {
      "x": -526089600000.0,
      "y": 0.0086890819795995
    }, {
      "x": -523411200000.0,
      "y": 0.009046362608367886
    }, {
      "x": -520819200000.0,
      "y": 0.004122938530734643
    }, {
      "x": -518140800000.0,
      "y": 0.005994754589734086
    }, {
      "x": -515462400000.0,
      "y": 0.009763424708974844
    }, {
      "x": -512870400000.0,
      "y": 0.009741476208317668
    }, {
      "x": -510192000000.0,
      "y": 0.005994754589734086
    }, {
      "x": -507600000000.0,
      "y": 0.005990265818045737
    }, {
      "x": -504921600000.0,
      "y": 0.011261261261261257
    }, {
      "x": -502243200000.0,
      "y": 0.015043249341857745
    }, {
      "x": -499824000000.0,
      "y": 0.011265490048817162
    }, {
      "x": -497145600000.0,
      "y": 0.006369426751592355
    }, {
      "x": -494553600000.0,
      "y": 0.008614232209737782
    }, {
      "x": -491875200000.0,
      "y": 0.00635039223010847
    }, {
      "x": -489283200000.0,
      "y": 0.0026129152668905586
    }, {
      "x": -486604800000.0,
      "y": 0.0
    }, {
      "x": -483926400000.0,
      "y": -0.002975083674228385
    }, {
      "x": -481334400000.0,
      "y": -0.008534322820037077
    }, {
      "x": -478656000000.0,
      "y": -0.0026070763500931626
    }, {
      "x": -476064000000.0,
      "y": -0.0037216226274656705
    }, {
      "x": -473385600000.0,
      "y": -0.006310319227913919
    }, {
      "x": -470707200000.0,
      "y": -0.006298629121896937
    }, {
      "x": -468288000000.0,
      "y": -0.00519866320089124
    }, {
      "x": -465609600000.0,
      "y": -0.002606105733432673
    }, {
      "x": -463017600000.0,
      "y": -0.005941329372447068
    }, {
      "x": -460339200000.0,
      "y": -0.008537490720118779
    }, {
      "x": -457747200000.0,
      "y": -0.0037230081906179935
    }, {
      "x": -455068800000.0,
      "y": -0.00484171322160154
    }, {
      "x": -452390400000.0,
      "y": 0.0014919806042521522
    }, {
      "x": -449798400000.0,
      "y": 0.0037425149700598404
    }, {
      "x": -447120000000.0,
      "y": 0.0037341299477220424
    }, {
      "x": -444528000000.0,
      "y": 0.0037355248412402897
    }, {
      "x": -441849600000.0,
      "y": 0.002241314904743996
    }, {
      "x": -439171200000.0,
      "y": 0.001491424310216205
    }, {
      "x": -436665600000.0,
      "y": 0.0037327360955581312
    }, {
      "x": -433987200000.0,
      "y": 0.005225830533781339
    }, {
      "x": -431395200000.0,
      "y": 0.009712364587224576
    }, {
      "x": -428716800000.0,
      "y": 0.01647323099962561
    }, {
      "x": -426124800000.0,
      "y": 0.019805680119581393
    }, {
      "x": -423446400000.0,
      "y": 0.02208083832335328
    }, {
      "x": -420768000000.0,
      "y": 0.01862197392923659
    }, {
      "x": -418176000000.0,
      "y": 0.02572706935123037
    }, {
      "x": -415497600000.0,
      "y": 0.0234375
    }, {
      "x": -412905600000.0,
      "y": 0.028284331968738252
    }, {
      "x": -410227200000.0,
      "y": 0.03130823704808061
    }, {
      "x": -407548800000.0,
      "y": 0.034996276991809516
    }, {
      "x": -405129600000.0,
      "y": 0.03607288955001864
    }, {
      "x": -402451200000.0,
      "y": 0.03713330857779429
    }, {
      "x": -399859200000.0,
      "y": 0.03588605253422128
    }, {
      "x": -397180800000.0,
      "y": 0.0353591160220994
    }, {
      "x": -394588800000.0,
      "y": 0.03297911322828884
    }, {
      "x": -391910400000.0,
      "y": 0.03551812522885389
    }, {
      "x": -389232000000.0,
      "y": 0.03546617915904937
    }, {
      "x": -386640000000.0,
      "y": 0.02944383860414379
    }, {
      "x": -383961600000.0,
      "y": 0.03271537622682663
    }, {
      "x": -381369600000.0,
      "y": 0.030401737242128135
    }, {
      "x": -378691200000.0,
      "y": 0.035056017347307566
    }, {
      "x": -376012800000.0,
      "y": 0.03237410071942448
    }, {
      "x": -373593600000.0,
      "y": 0.03625269203158665
    }, {
      "x": -370915200000.0,
      "y": 0.036161833154314316
    }, {
      "x": -368323200000.0,
      "y": 0.033571428571428585
    }, {
      "x": -365644800000.0,
      "y": 0.028459622909996485
    }, {
      "x": -363052800000.0,
      "y": 0.02483150053210359
    }, {
      "x": -360374400000.0,
      "y": 0.023338048090523422
    }, {
      "x": -357696000000.0,
      "y": 0.02083333333333326
    }, {
      "x": -355104000000.0,
      "y": 0.02083333333333326
    }, {
      "x": -352425600000.0,
      "y": 0.019007391763463444
    }, {
      "x": -349833600000.0,
      "y": 0.017562346329469625
    }, {
      "x": -347155200000.0,
      "y": 0.012918994413407825
    }, {
      "x": -344476800000.0,
      "y": 0.010452961672473782
    }, {
      "x": -342057600000.0,
      "y": 0.003463803255975062
    }, {
      "x": -339379200000.0,
      "y": 0.0013821700069107656
    }, {
      "x": -336787200000.0,
      "y": 0.003455425017277136
    }, {
      "x": -334108800000.0,
      "y": 0.006918021445866396
    }, {
      "x": -331516800000.0,
      "y": 0.008999653859466772
    }, {
      "x": -328838400000.0,
      "y": 0.008293020041465038
    }, {
      "x": -326160000000.0,
      "y": 0.011760636457972984
    }, {
      "x": -323568000000.0,
      "y": 0.015219647180906293
    }, {
      "x": -320889600000.0,
      "y": 0.013816925734024155
    }, {
      "x": -318297600000.0,
      "y": 0.015188125647221273
    }, {
      "x": -315619200000.0,
      "y": 0.012409513960703222
    }, {
      "x": -312940800000.0,
      "y": 0.014137931034482687
    }, {
      "x": -310435200000.0,
      "y": 0.015188125647221273
    }, {
      "x": -307756800000.0,
      "y": 0.019323671497584405
    }, {
      "x": -305164800000.0,
      "y": 0.018250688705234275
    }, {
      "x": -302486400000.0,
      "y": 0.017176228100309165
    }, {
      "x": -299894400000.0,
      "y": 0.013722126929674117
    }, {
      "x": -297216000000.0,
      "y": 0.01473612063056895
    }, {
      "x": -294537600000.0,
      "y": 0.012307692307692353
    }, {
      "x": -291945600000.0,
      "y": 0.013628620102214661
    }, {
      "x": -289267200000.0,
      "y": 0.014650766609880739
    }, {
      "x": -286675200000.0,
      "y": 0.013600816048962905
    }, {
      "x": -283996800000.0,
      "y": 0.016002723867892366
    }, {
      "x": -281318400000.0,
      "y": 0.014620877252635056
    }, {
      "x": -278899200000.0,
      "y": 0.014620877252635056
    }, {
      "x": -276220800000.0,
      "y": 0.009140148950575577
    }, {
      "x": -273628800000.0,
      "y": 0.009130875887723988
    }, {
      "x": -270950400000.0,
      "y": 0.0077676460655184965
    }, {
      "x": -268358400000.0,
      "y": 0.012521150592216701
    }, {
      "x": -265680000000.0,
      "y": 0.011144883485309176
    }, {
      "x": -263001600000.0,
      "y": 0.012495778453225359
    }, {
      "x": -260409600000.0,
      "y": 0.007731092436974896
    }, {
      "x": -257731200000.0,
      "y": 0.00671591672263272
    }, {
      "x": -255139200000.0,
      "y": 0.006709158000671067
    }, {
      "x": -252460800000.0,
      "y": 0.006702412868632601
    }, {
      "x": -249782400000.0,
      "y": 0.009048257372654245
    }, {
      "x": -247363200000.0,
      "y": 0.011058981233244003
    }, {
      "x": -244684800000.0,
      "y": 0.013418316001341912
    }, {
      "x": -242092800000.0,
      "y": 0.013404825737265424
    }, {
      "x": -239414400000.0,
      "y": 0.012399463806970434
    }, {
      "x": -236822400000.0,
      "y": 0.010026737967914423
    }, {
      "x": -234144000000.0,
      "y": 0.011356045424181671
    }, {
      "x": -231465600000.0,
      "y": 0.014676450967311627
    }, {
      "x": -228873600000.0,
      "y": 0.013342228152101399
    }, {
      "x": -226195200000.0,
      "y": 0.013342228152101399
    }, {
      "x": -223603200000.0,
      "y": 0.012329223592135952
    }, {
      "x": -220924800000.0,
      "y": 0.013315579227696439
    }, {
      "x": -218246400000.0,
      "y": 0.012288276320159497
    }, {
      "x": -215827200000.0,
      "y": 0.011269472986410234
    }, {
      "x": -213148800000.0,
      "y": 0.00893743793445867
    }, {
      "x": -210556800000.0,
      "y": 0.008928571428571619
    }, {
      "x": -207878400000.0,
      "y": 0.013240648791790655
    }, {
      "x": -205286400000.0,
      "y": 0.015552614162806178
    }, {
      "x": -202608000000.0,
      "y": 0.015521796565389767
    }, {
      "x": -199929600000.0,
      "y": 0.009861932938855844
    }, {
      "x": -197337600000.0,
      "y": 0.012179065174456882
    }, {
      "x": -194659200000.0,
      "y": 0.013166556945358954
    }, {
      "x": -192067200000.0,
      "y": 0.016458196181698526
    }, {
      "x": -189388800000.0,
      "y": 0.016425755584756896
    }, {
      "x": -186710400000.0,
      "y": 0.014107611548556331
    }, {
      "x": -184204800000.0,
      "y": 0.014093739757456536
    }, {
      "x": -181526400000.0,
      "y": 0.015419947506561726
    }, {
      "x": -178934400000.0,
      "y": 0.015404785316289749
    }, {
      "x": -176256000000.0,
      "y": 0.013067624959163693
    }, {
      "x": -173664000000.0,
      "y": 0.010752688172043001
    }, {
      "x": -170985600000.0,
      "y": 0.009756097560975618
    }, {
      "x": -168307200000.0,
      "y": 0.01171875
    }, {
      "x": -165715200000.0,
      "y": 0.012032520325203189
    }, {
      "x": -163036800000.0,
      "y": 0.013970110461338558
    }, {
      "x": -160444800000.0,
      "y": 0.011981865284974136
    }, {
      "x": -157766400000.0,
      "y": 0.01098901098901095
    }, {
      "x": -155088000000.0,
      "y": 0.011970236169524417
    }, {
      "x": -152668800000.0,
      "y": 0.011958629605688387
    }, {
      "x": -149990400000.0,
      "y": 0.013893376413570246
    }, {
      "x": -147398400000.0,
      "y": 0.0161394448030987
    }, {
      "x": -144720000000.0,
      "y": 0.019348597226700903
    }, {
      "x": -142128000000.0,
      "y": 0.01805286911669879
    }, {
      "x": -139449600000.0,
      "y": 0.016103059581320522
    }, {
      "x": -136771200000.0,
      "y": 0.01737451737451745
    }, {
      "x": -134179200000.0,
      "y": 0.017030848329048665
    }, {
      "x": -131500800000.0,
      "y": 0.017302146747837144
    }, {
      "x": -128908800000.0,
      "y": 0.019200000000000106
    }, {
      "x": -126230400000.0,
      "y": 0.019181585677749302
    }, {
      "x": -123552000000.0,
      "y": 0.025575447570332477
    }, {
      "x": -121132800000.0,
      "y": 0.027786649632705274
    }, {
      "x": -118454400000.0,
      "y": 0.028680688336520044
    }, {
      "x": -115862400000.0,
      "y": 0.02763659466327839
    }, {
      "x": -113184000000.0,
      "y": 0.024359379943056148
    }, {
      "x": -110592000000.0,
      "y": 0.02754908169727699
    }, {
      "x": -107913600000.0,
      "y": 0.034865293185419866
    }, {
      "x": -105235200000.0,
      "y": 0.035736875395319334
    }, {
      "x": -102643200000.0,
      "y": 0.03791469194312813
    }, {
      "x": -99964800000.0,
      "y": 0.03559055118110255
    }, {
      "x": -97372800000.0,
      "y": 0.033594976452119285
    }, {
      "x": -94694400000.0,
      "y": 0.0319949811794229
    }, {
      "x": -92016000000.0,
      "y": 0.028678304239401653
    }, {
      "x": -89596800000.0,
      "y": 0.025481665630826544
    }, {
      "x": -86918400000.0,
      "y": 0.025402726146220633
    }, {
      "x": -84326400000.0,
      "y": 0.023183925811437467
    }, {
      "x": -81648000000.0,
      "y": 0.028412600370598895
    }, {
      "x": -79056000000.0,
      "y": 0.029275808936825687
    }, {
      "x": -76377600000.0,
      "y": 0.026033690658499253
    }, {
      "x": -73699200000.0,
      "y": 0.025954198473282508
    }, {
      "x": -71107200000.0,
      "y": 0.025875190258751957
    }, {
      "x": -68428800000.0,
      "y": 0.0310218978102188
    }, {
      "x": -65836800000.0,
      "y": 0.03280680437424044
    }, {
      "x": -63158400000.0,
      "y": 0.03647416413373872
    }, {
      "x": -60480000000.0,
      "y": 0.036363636363636376
    }, {
      "x": -57974400000.0,
      "y": 0.039393939393939315
    }, {
      "x": -55296000000.0,
      "y": 0.0392749244712991
    }, {
      "x": -52704000000.0,
      "y": 0.04229607250755274
    }, {
      "x": -50025600000.0,
      "y": 0.042042042042042205
    }, {
      "x": -47433600000.0,
      "y": 0.04491017964071853
    }, {
      "x": -44755200000.0,
      "y": 0.04477611940298498
    }, {
      "x": -42076800000.0,
      "y": 0.044642857142857206
    }, {
      "x": -39484800000.0,
      "y": 0.047477744807121525
    }, {
      "x": -36806400000.0,
      "y": 0.04424778761061954
    }, {
      "x": -34214400000.0,
      "y": 0.04705882352941182
    }, {
      "x": -31536000000.0,
      "y": 0.04692082111436946
    }, {
      "x": -28857600000.0,
      "y": 0.04678362573099393
    }, {
      "x": -26438400000.0,
      "y": 0.05247813411078739
    }, {
      "x": -23760000000.0,
      "y": 0.05523255813953476
    }, {
      "x": -21168000000.0,
      "y": 0.05507246376811592
    }, {
      "x": -18489600000.0,
      "y": 0.054755043227665556
    }, {
      "x": -15897600000.0,
      "y": 0.054441260744985565
    }, {
      "x": -13219200000.0,
      "y": 0.05428571428571427
    }, {
      "x": -10540800000.0,
      "y": 0.056980056980056926
    }, {
      "x": -7948800000.0,
      "y": 0.056657223796034106
    }, {
      "x": -5270400000.0,
      "y": 0.05932203389830515
    }, {
      "x": -2678400000.0,
      "y": 0.0589887640449438
    }, {
      "x": 0.0,
      "y": 0.06162464985994376
    }, {
      "x": 2678400000.0,
      "y": 0.06424581005586605
    }, {
      "x": 5097600000.0,
      "y": 0.06094182825484751
    }, {
      "x": 7776000000.0,
      "y": 0.060606060606060774
    }, {
      "x": 10368000000.0,
      "y": 0.06043956043956045
    }, {
      "x": 13046400000.0,
      "y": 0.060109289617486183
    }, {
      "x": 15638400000.0,
      "y": 0.057065217391304435
    }, {
      "x": 18316800000.0,
      "y": 0.05691056910569103
    }, {
      "x": 20995200000.0,
      "y": 0.05660377358490565
    }, {
      "x": 23587200000.0,
      "y": 0.05630026809651478
    }, {
      "x": 26265600000.0,
      "y": 0.05600000000000005
    }, {
      "x": 28857600000.0,
      "y": 0.055702917771883076
    }, {
      "x": 31536000000.0,
      "y": 0.05277044854881274
    }, {
      "x": 34214400000.0,
      "y": 0.04724409448818889
    }, {
      "x": 36633600000.0,
      "y": 0.044386422976501416
    }, {
      "x": 39312000000.0,
      "y": 0.04155844155844157
    }, {
      "x": 41904000000.0,
      "y": 0.04404145077720201
    }, {
      "x": 44582400000.0,
      "y": 0.04381443298969079
    }, {
      "x": 47174400000.0,
      "y": 0.04370179948586128
    }, {
      "x": 49852800000.0,
      "y": 0.04358974358974366
    }, {
      "x": 52531200000.0,
      "y": 0.04081632653061207
    }, {
      "x": 55123200000.0,
      "y": 0.038071065989847774
    }, {
      "x": 57801600000.0,
      "y": 0.03535353535353525
    }, {
      "x": 60393600000.0,
      "y": 0.03266331658291466
    }]
  }],

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```